# How do I use Launchy gem for an array?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to open all of the urls in an array in my browser using the ruby gem Launchy but i can't seem to get it to work, any help is appreciated

```
require 'Launchy'
a = ["msn.com","yahoo.com","blizzard.com"]
Launchy.open(a[0..2])
```

I can get it to work with just Launchy.open(a[0]) or whatever value i want but not the whole range

Comment: Have you tried using `.each`? Example:  `a.each { |url| Launchy.open(url) }`

Answer (score 0):

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056117/dan) commented you should iterate the urls and call `Launchy.open` for each one of them. So, in your case, this code should do the work:

```rb
require 'launchy'

urls = ['msn.com', 'yahoo.com', 'blizzard.com']

urls.each { |url| Launchy.open(url) }
```